# Gatsby starter, cant find html tag in "view source code"

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

I started using this starter (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog) but I don't see the html tags if I go in the source html code of the generated page. I need the html tags to be rendewred and present in html source code because of SEO

Comment: I dont see the "html source code", I think might be something related to the service worker which is used by the starter template but Im not sure

Comment: What do you want to do that you can't do here? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/blob/master/src/components/seo.js